# How can I split an xts object in by-monthly periods?

Tags: r, split, endpoint, xts

For example if I create the following xts object:
index <- seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "day", length.out = 100)
xts_object <- xts(rnorm(100), order.by = index)

I can split into one-month period with the "split" function:
list_object <- split(xts_object, f = "months")

And I can find the endpoints in my index that correspond to the last by-monthly points with "endpoints":
endpoints <- endpoints(xts_object, on = "months", k = 2)

But I how can I split my time series based on those endpoints?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just figured it out. Split also has `k` argument, so it's straightforward:

```
list_object <- split(xts_object, f = "months", k = 2)
```